# R: finding rows of one matrix in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

We start with:

```
m1 = matrix(c(1:32), ncol=4, byrow = T); m2 = matrix(c(1:16), ncol=4, byrow=T);
```

if it is not obvious, this will make 2 matrices, one is 8x4 the other is 4x4 such that the first 4 rows of the former are identical to that of the latter.

I want a function with sudo/semi code below;

```
#x is always the bigger; an if check can be put here but assume nrow(x) > nrow(y)
countAinB<-function(x, y){

#new matrix of 0s that has the same dim of x, add 1 extra column for adding found/not found (0/1) coding
c <-matrix(0, ncol(x)+1, nrow(x))


#need change of for, it is slow in R
for (i in 1:nrow(y)){
    #bad R below
    if(y[i,] in x){
    ??add a 1 to the column matching the found row of y in x to c
}}
return(c)
}
C <- countAinB(M1,M2)
```

Now C, is a matrix identical to X, except it has a column of 0s and 1s indicating M2 was found in M1.

My real datasets are huge, so trying to find best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.table` is a fast solution for this type of problem:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- data.table(m1)
DT2 <- data.table(cbind(m2, 0), key=paste0("V", seq(len=ncol(m2))))
setnames(DT2, c(head(names(DT2), -1L), "found"))
DT2[DT1, list(found=ifelse(is.na(found), 0, 1))]
```

Here, we are LEFT JOINING `DT2` to `DT1` using the first four columns of each.  This produces:

```
#    V1 V2 V3 V4 found
# 1:  1  2  3  4     1
# 2:  5  6  7  8     1
# 3:  9 10 11 12     1
# 4: 13 14 15 16     1
# 5: 17 18 19 20     0
# 6: 21 22 23 24     0
# 7: 25 26 27 28     0
# 8: 29 30 31 32     0
```

Where `found` indicates whether the row was present in both objects.  You can convert back to matrix with `as.matrix`.

Comment: I get this error if I change ncols from 4 to 5 since your method is not dynamic about incoming matrices "Error in `[.data.table`(DT2, DT1, list(found = ifelse(is.na(found), 0,  : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey."

Comment: @StudentOfScience, the edited version should work for arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: Thank you, but the is.na() has V5 which is not the case, so can I get it from DT2?

Comment: @StudentOfScience, okay, one more try, now we rename DT2 so the last column is `found`.  Hopefully this works.

Comment: You just edited the setname() that I was going to suggest as R warned me about it. Also, instead of names, that does not work for me, i am using colnames() which works. Thx so much!