# Efficiently and elegantly check which rows of a matrix exist in another

Tags: r

Say we want to check which rows in a matrix (or dataframe) exist in another.  All the solutions I've found to this surely basic operation seem to either require a library (this [{data.table} 4-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21654007/1156245)) or are verbose and obscure, such as:

```
(m1 = matrix(1:10, ncol=2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
(m2 = matrix(c(1,3,4,-1,6,7,9,8), ncol=2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    3    7
[3,]    4    9
[4,]   -1    8

# ugh!
rowSums(outer(m2[,1], m1[,1], "==") & outer(m2[,2], m1[,2], "==")) != 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Does anyone know a more elegant method using base functions, with equivalent efficiency to this example?  (NB. `apply()` is not as efficient..)

Comment: Elegance is obviously in the eye of the beholder, because that `rowSums` one-liner is pretty elegant to me,

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not easy to dash off - people like me are going to have to refer to notes.  IMO R's strength lies in being closer to natural language.

Comment: In case you want to also consider a package-solution, try `dplyr::intersect(m1, m2)` (if they are data.frames)

Comment: Perhaps `duplicated(rbind(m2, m1), fromLast=TRUE)[1:nrow(m2)]`

Comment: @docendo-discimus `dplyr::intersect(data.frame(m1), data.frame(m2))` gives "Error: not compatible"

Comment: Can we assume that rows are unique in each matrix?

Comment: Not in my case, but it might be worth detailing that solution for when anyone does.

Comment: @akrun alas I've spotted your method fails for the case `m1 = matrix(0, ncol=2, nrow=5); m2 = matrix(1, ncol=2, nrow=2)`

Comment: @geotheory I haven't checked all the possible scenarios.  Thanks for the comment.  Your solution looks pretty good for two columns.  Otherwise, `intersect` suggested by docendodiscimus is robust to get the rows

Comment: @geotheory Other option for two column matrix would be to use paste i.e `paste0(m2[,1], m2[,2]) %in% paste0(m1[,1], m1[,2])`

Comment: Yes I've used that in the past: it's less efficient for big matrices / more so for small ones, but also not width agnostic.  I still can't get `intersect` to work.  Can someone possibly check?  `dplyr` is credible enough to be a worthy solution if efficient.

Comment: @geotheory `intersect` works for me.  I am using `dplyr_0.4.0`

Comment: @docendo-discimus could you possibly add your full code as an answer so we can test it and comment there?  I can't get it to work on R 3.1.2 / dplyr 0.4.1 on Win or Mac.

Comment: So much for `intersect`..

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12697344/2588463) you can use match:

```
> m1 = matrix(1:10, ncol=2)
> m2 = matrix(c(1,3,4,-1,6,7,9,8), ncol=2)
> m<-match(data.frame(t(m1)), data.frame(t(m2)))
> m
[1]  1 NA NA  3 NA
```

You can easily change the result of `match` to suit your preferred format:

```
> !is.na(m)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
> which(!is.na(m))
[1] 1 4
```

You can retrieve the rows using any of those variants:

```
> m1[!is.na(m),]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    4    9
```

But if you actually wanted that and not the indexes, just use `merge` (returns a `data.frame`):

```
> merge(m1, m2)
  V1 V2
1  1  6
2  4  9
```